# multiple servers porting to each other

Tags: vps, port-forwarding, desktop

here is the **details:**
theres is who "servers": VPS with ubuntu 10.10x32 and home pc, win7
on win7 apatche2.2 is running with webpage
on VPS game server is running
DNS forwards www subdomain to PC, and everything else to VPS (all via ip)
I can not configure DNS directly, my providers do

Wanted **result:**
DNS forwards everything to VPS,
VPS redirects *:80 to PC
when viewing page stored in PC domain is shown normaly

**Questions:**
How to achieve that using as minimal resources as possible?
Is it possible just tel my DNS provider to fix it that :80 port is in different ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to achieve that using as minimal resources as possible?

Install web-server(Apache(mod_proxy), nginx, lighttpd) and configure proxy to PC.

> Is it possible just tel my DNS provider to fix it that :80 port is in different ip?

No, you can use two domain: example.com(VDS) and www.example.com(PC)

Comment: just apatche mod_proxy? and nginx AND lighttpd or comma stads as OR? apatche could do it, i know but its way too heavy to use since only proxi forwarding is needed

Comment: nginx it will be, also i got recommendation for cherokee. thanx